# How to access facebook new "Interest List" in facebook graph api

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I am searching a way to access user "Interest List", which facebook recently launched(http://www.facebook.com/addlist),through facebook graph API. Pleas help me.

Comment: Seems to be still facebook does not publish a method for access Interest List. But In this point I am wondering why still facebook is getting time to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get **user interest list** you can use the following link

https://graph.facebook.com/me/interests

with proper access token of **user_likes** and **friend_likes** permission.

Comment: the api says "/interests = The interests listed on the person's profile.", this is not the new interest list feature, or am I missing something here?